# How can i call JUST ONCE a function when a variable changes its value? c#

Tags: c#, variables, properties, getter

Imagine I have an **int count**, and every time it gets changed i want to call the function **DoSomething()** how could i do it?

I think i have to use properties somehow (and would like how to know how to do it with a property), but any help will be great.

Comment: set up a flag and change it via a method/property?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's only a bazillion C# property examples on the internet.

Comment: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @SamAxe well, so i can't find the solution, i find how to call it; but not how to call it just once every time it changes.

Comment: @SirRufo I'm not working on c# 6.0

Comment: Your C# version has no interfaces and events? You should add that important detail to your question

Comment: BTW if ( !Equals( oldValue, newValue ) ) { doWhatever(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is use a public property for accessing the `Count`, and store the value of the property in a private backing field. This way you can compare the incoming `value` in the setter (which is called when someone is setting the `Count` property) to the current `count`. If it's different, then call `DoSomething` (and update your backing field):

**Property with backing field and custom setter**

```
private int count = 0;

public int Count
{
    get
    {
        return count;
    }
    set
    {
        // Only do something if the value is changing
        if (value != count)
        {
            DoSomething();
            count = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
static class Program
{
    private static int count = 0;

    public static int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return count;
        }
        set
        {
            // Only do something if the value is changing
            if (value != count)
            {
                DoSomething();
                count = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something!");
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        Count = 1; // Will 'DoSomething'
        Count = 1; // Will NOT DoSomething since we're not changing the value
        Count = 3; // Will DoSomething

        Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you a ton! That is the answer I was looking for

Comment: Great, feel free to mark as answered! :)